# Core Data - running through relational objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am new to core data, I have 3 entities where
categories has many subcategories the in turn has many shops.
they way I represent it in my app is the most natural way of master-detail-detail table view controllers.

My problem comes, where I want a category for example, not to show to a user if its subcategories are empty of stores under some condition (e.g the user chose to turn off stores that are too far from him).

In SQL I would perform some kind of join but I'm not sure how to do it in core data, I basically need to perform some kind of "filter" on the shops of that category, and if its empty, not to show the category.

My current solution which I'm guessing is bad, is to get all the subcategories of a category with a predicate, and on each of them run if they are empty of stores under the terms provided, if all of them are empty, I don't show the category.

Any more natural solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"subcategories.shops.@COUNT != 0"];
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how with all the guides I have read, I could have missed that core data offers such a simple dot syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your data model correctly, performing `fetchRequest` with such predicate should help you:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"subcategories.shops != nil)"];
```